Open Native Outlook App in Logged-In State
I’m working on a Flutter app with a dashboard with an Outlook icon. When the user clicks on the Outlook icon, I get a login URL that successfully opens in the browser and logs in to the user’s Outlook account. The URL looks something like this:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=***********&redirect_uri=**********&response_mode=form_post&response_type=code+id_token&scope=openid&msafed=1&msaredir=1&login_hint=*********&client-request-id=************&protectedtoken=true

Problem:
I want to open the native Outlook app on the user's device (if installed) in a logged-in state, bypassing the need to log in again. If the Outlook app is not installed, I want to redirect the user to the Google Play Store to install it.
What I have tried:
WebView: I can open the login URL in a WebView, but it only logs the user in via the browser and doesn’t open the Outlook app.
External browsers: Using url_launcher to open the login URL in an external browser works for the web version of Outlook, but I want to open the native app.
URL Schemes: I tried looking into ms-outlook:// URL schemes, but I couldn't achieve the login state transition properly.
Desired Solution:
If the Outlook app is installed, my Flutter app should directly open the Outlook app in a logged-in state using SSO from the OAuth login flow.
If the app is not installed, it should open the Google Play Store for the user to install Outlook.
Flutter Packages I Have Tried:

url_launcher
external_app_launcher
app_links


Package external_app_launcher would help.
If not, check if you have added Outlook's package name com.microsoft.office.outlook to <queries> in AndroidManifest.xml.

How can I access it in the login-state? I want to use a user_specific login via login URL.

Have you try MSAL? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/msal-android-single-sign-on .

Not yet. How can i  integrate MSAL SDK

Oh, follow the steps in Prerequisites : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/msal-android-single-sign-on#prerequisites
